# jquery post url parameters comparison with python not working

Tags: jquery, python-2.7, tornado

Iam using jquery AJAX request using post methid to send parameters to tornado server and did something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/leave_action?id=" + rowid.id + "&action=" + param,
    dataType: "json",
    async: false
  })
```

But when I'm comparing using python, it is not working:

```
action = str(self.get_query_argument("action"))
print action  #here am getting either approve or decline 
  if action == "approve":
     print "approved"
  elif action == "decline":
     print "declined"
```

I tried with `is` also but no luck.

I also tried with:

```
      action = self.get_query_argument("action")
      a=action.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

but no use.

Comment: What library are you using? your question doesn't have enough information in it.

Comment: Yes, ``tornado`` is very useful information. Otherwise your post have absolutely no reference to what you're using to do this.

Comment: Your ``if/elif`` statement looks like it starts on a different block. If there's more info in between it would be helpful to see it. But try something like this anyway (might have whitespace surrounding):
``if action.strip() == "approve"``

Comment: It likely has some whitespace surrounded in it. ``strip`` strips whitespace from a string. You can see exactly what whitespace is causing it by printing something like this: ``print("'%s'" % action)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some points you better to know ! The Tornado is a MVC based framework that let you have a lot of things in your hand.

So, you can set URL pattern instead using query string. that's mean you don't need to get value with `self.get_query_argument()` or `self.get_argument()`.

For URL:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'^(?i)/leave_action/([\w+^/])/([\w+^/])[/]?$', YourLeaveActionHandler)
], **settings)
```

or even:

```
application = tornado.web.Application([
    (r'/leave_action/(id)/(approve|decline)', YourLeaveActionHandler, None, "this_url_name")
], **settings)
```

The second URL pattern is better a bit. because we emphasize expressly the first group should be `id` and the second group should `approve` OR `decline`.

And in your handler:

```
class YourLeaveActionHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, id, action):
        print id
        print action

    def post(self, id, action):
        print id
        print action

        if action == "approve":
            print "approved"
        elif action == "decline":
            print "declined"
```

In your handler , the `action` should be `approve` OR `decline` and anything else expect these not accepted in this handler. So you can easily compare the action value.

- And you should note this,sometimes when you using POST method, the query string maybe ignored by tornado.